# TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

Guys I have this function from a wordpress plugin:

```
jQuery( '#widget-twitter-__i__-username' ).on( 'change', function() {
  jQuery('#widget-twitter-__i__-list' ).val(0);
});

jQuery( '#widget-twitter-__i__-list' ).on( 'change', function() {
  jQuery('#widget-twitter-__i__-username' ).val(0);
});
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function
```

When I click that error on the error console, I get to the above code.

And I was wondering what would be the way to address this issue.

Comment: jquery version used?

Comment: this method is not available in jQuery < 1.7

Comment: @A.Wolff since it is saying `jQuery(...).on` I think jQuery is loaded, but a old version else it has to say `jQuery` is undefied

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your jQuery version is under 1.7 i'd suggest using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or update your jQuery to the latest version

```
jQuery( '#widget-twitter-__i__-list' ).delegate(
```

or

```
jQuery( '#widget-twitter-__i__-list' ).live(
```

Comment: let me try this Anton :)